# Fill a domain defined by three inequalities

Tags: tikz-pgf

For an exercise I want to represent graphically the domain of a definition of a function.
This domain is described by three inequalities.

[image]

This is what I have done so far.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

% Arc from (-sqrt(2)/2,-sqrt(2)/2) to (sqrt(2)/2,sqrt(2)/2)
\draw[dashed] (225:1) arc (225:45:1) ;
  
  % Ligne y = x
  \draw[domain=-2:-sqrt(2)/2,smooth,variable=\x,dashed] plot ({\x},{\x});
    \draw[domain=sqrt(2)/2:2,smooth,variable=\x,dashed] plot ({\x},{\x});
  
  % Ligne verticale x = 2
  \draw[very thick] (2,2) -- (2,3);
  
  % Axes
  \draw[dotted,->] (-2,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw[dotted,->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above] {$y$};
  
  % Étiquettes
  \node at (1,1) [yshift=1cm, above right] {$y=x$};
  \node at (2,1) [right,yshift=2.5cm] {$x=2$};
  \node at (1.2,0.5) [xshift = -3cm, above left] {$x^2+y^2=1$};
  
  % Légende pour le domaine
  \node at (3.5,1) [right,align=left] {Domaine de définition :\\(à l'extérieur du cercle, au-dessus de $y=x$,\\à gauche de $x=2$)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces the figure below

[image]

How can one fill this domain producing a figure similar to the figure (d) below?

[image]

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In its dumbest version: `\fill[lightgray] (-2,-2) -- (225:1) arc[start angle=225, delta angle=-180, radius=1] -- (2,2) -- (2,3) -| cycle;`. (These are very easy functions but you can also concatenate plots: `\fill[lightgray] plot[domain=-2:-sqrt(2)/2] (\x,\x) -- plot[domain=225:45] (\x:1) -- plot[domain=sqrt(2)/2:2] (\x,\x) -- (2,3) -| cycle;`)

Comment: For more complex functions (and intersecting points) look into the [tag:fillbetween] library from PGFPlots or the `spath3` library (and the many Q&A on this site).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[cyan!40,opacity=.3] (-4,-4) rectangle (2,5);
        \fill[white] (-4,-4)--(2,-4)--(2,2)--cycle;
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt] (2,2)--(2,5);
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt,dashed] plot[domain=-4:2] (\x,\x);
        \fill[white] (0,0) circle(1);
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt,dashed] (.707,.707) arc(45:225:1);
        \draw[gray!30] (-4,-4) grid (4,5);
        \draw[-latex] (-4.2,0)--(4.3,0) node[right] () {\footnotesize $x$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
        \draw (\i,-0)--(\i,-0.1) node[below] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4.2)--(0,5.3) node[above] () {\footnotesize $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,5}
        \draw (0,\i)--(-.1,\i) node[left] () {\footnotesize \i};
        \draw (-.2,-.2) node () {\footnotesize $O$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: To avoid 'double' vertical line, moove this line of the code:

\draw[blue,line width=2pt] (2,2)--(2,5);

as the last line inside the `tikzpicture` environment.